# Postgresql server will not start

Tags: service, windows-service, logging, postgresql

I'm on Windows 7. I restarted my computer. I then tried to connect to the database and got an error. I don't remember which one in particular but it was some connection issue. I decided to try to restart the server, so I clicked on "Restart server" from the start menu. This blocked. After a few minutes  I killed the process and tried again, only to get a "The service is starting or stopping.  Please try again later." message.

I rebooted the computer again, tried to start again, and got the same error. I killed the `pg_ctl` process and tried starting it manually, but that didn't work either:

```
C:\Users\DrClaud>cscript "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.3\scripts\serverctl.vbs"
 start wait
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


The PostgreSQL Server 8.3 service is starting...................................
.......................................
The PostgreSQL Server 8.3 service could not be started.

The service did not report an error.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534.

The start command returned an error (2)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to check your logs (either the PostgreSQL log in $PGDATA\pg_log or the Windows eventlog), and then you're better of reporting this issue on the pgsql-general mailinglist for a quick answer, unlesss the log messages make it clear to you what the problem is.

Comment: ty for the tips. i ended up reinstalling cause I had my DB backed up, heh.